# TinyMce Insert Image

Tags: tinymce

I am looking for a solution that allows me to insert an image and resize it in tinymce,any ideas?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tinyMCE package comes by default with such feature. Plugin name is Image. The button should be in the toolbar on line 2. However you should use the advanced theme to activate it. In your `tinyMCE.init( { ... } );` set `theme : "advanced"`

Comment: What's the name of the plugin?.The one that i see is advimage.Its kind of complex.I only need one that allows me to upload the image(via a link or uploading) into the editor and visually edit while in the editor and save.